# VB 2010 not running through my whole program

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have been working on my VB program over the past few weeks and each homework assignment is to add more stuff to it.  Up until this week everything has ran smoothly.  Now all of a sudden the program shows my splash screen and jumps to my about box but does not show my main form.  I have no errors and it builds successfully and compiles.

```
Public Class Checkbook

    Dim currentBalance As Decimal = CDec(500.0)
    Dim depositAmount As Decimal
    Dim checkAmount As Decimal
    Dim serviceBalance As Decimal
    Dim serviceFee As Decimal
    Dim depositCount As Decimal
    Dim serviceAmount As Decimal
    Dim enteredAmount As Decimal

    Function checkBalance() As Decimal
        'this function allows the user to check their current balance
        Dim enteredAmount As String = transAmount.Text
        serviceFee = 10
        balanceLabel.Text = currentBalance.ToString("C")
        Return currentBalance
    End Function

    Function deposit() As Decimal
        'this function adds the transaction amount to the balance
        enteredAmount = Decimal.Parse(transAmount.Text)
        depositAmount = (currentBalance + enteredAmount)
        currentBalance = depositAmount
        Summary.depositList.Items.Add(depositAmount)
        balanceLabel.Text = currentBalance.ToString("C")
        Return currentBalance
    End Function
    Function check() As Decimal
        'this function takes the check amount and sbutracts its from the balance
        enteredAmount = Decimal.Parse(transAmount.Text)
        checkAmount = (currentBalance - enteredAmount)
        currentBalance = checkAmount
        Summary.amountList.Items.Add(checkAmount)
        Return currentBalance
        'gives a service charge if balance will be negative
        If currentBalance < 0 Then
            currentBalance = currentBalance - 10
            Summary.feesList.Items.Add(serviceFee)
            MessageBox.Show("Negative Balance Fee Applied", "Attention: Fee Incurred")
            Return currentBalance
        End If
    End Function
    Function service() As Decimal
        'this transaction subtracts the service charge from the balance
        enteredAmount = Decimal.Parse(transAmount.Text)
        serviceAmount = (currentBalance - (10 + enteredAmount))
        currentBalance = serviceAmount
        Summary.amountList.Items.Add(serviceAmount)
        balanceLabel.Text = currentBalance.ToString
        Return currentBalance
    End Function



    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
        'exits form
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub AboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles AboutToolStripMenuItem.Click
        'gives information about program
        AboutBox.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SummaryToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SummaryToolStripMenuItem.Click
        'shows summary of transactions
        Summary.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub CalculateToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CalculateToolStripMenuItem.Click
        'gives orders for what function to call
        If balanceButton.Checked Then
            Call checkBalance()
        ElseIf checkButton.Checked Then
            Call check()
        ElseIf depositButton.Checked Then
            Call deposit()
        ElseIf serviceRadioButton.Checked Then
            Call service()

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub FontToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles FontToolStripMenuItem.Click
        'allows user to change font type and size
        With FontDialog1
            .Font = balanceLabel.Font
            .ShowDialog()
            balanceLabel.Font = .Font

        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub ColorToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ColorToolStripMenuItem.Click
        'allows user to change font color
        With ColorDialog1
            .Color = balanceLabel.ForeColor
            .ShowDialog()
            balanceLabel.ForeColor = .Color

        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This sounds like a great opportunity to familiarize yourself with Visual Studio's debugging features.  Place debugging breakpoints at strategic lines of code in your application and run the application in debug mode.  It will pause execution on those breakpoints and allow you to step through the running code, examine the run-time values of your variables, and observe the run-time behavior.  When doing this, where specifically does the behavior differ from what you expect?

Comment: My splash screen opens and runs then instead of running my actual program form it pulls up my About form which was a button on my main form in its menu.

Answer (score 0):

> My splash screen opens and runs then instead of running my actual program form it pulls up my About form

Sounds like your About form is the default form that the application is set to launch when it first runs.  Somewhere in your code there is a `static void Main` method.  That method should have the code which opens the first form.  It might be something like this:

```
Application.Run(new AboutForm());
```

You would want to change that to the desired form:

```
Application.Run(new SomeOtherForm());
```